# IIS APPPOOL Mysterious User

Tags: asp.net, iis

There is a similar question pertaining to my topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004440/userprincipal-current-returns-apppool-on-iis), but it doesn't fully satisfy the issue I'm having. Going off the question in the link, how would the apppool identity get used as the current user? My application actually gets the users out of a SQL db, but the apppool identity is not in the db, yet still gets logged as the current user. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your appPool identity IS the current user, as far as IIS is concerned. IIS has no knowledge of any account that you are storing in your application's SQL database. When you enable Anonymous authentication, you can change the account that IIS uses to access your sites and applications. By default, IIS 7 uses "IUSR" as the user name for anonymous access, however you can change this to "Application pool identity" if you want to restrict access that way."IUSR" user name is created when you install IIS 7.Any clients connecting to the application will be connecting as either "IUSR" or  "IIS AppPool/{AppPoolName}". I am guessing that your function to log the current user is reading from the SQL information and not from your HTTPcontext. More information about Application Pool Identity here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770966%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, the application does initially read the user from the SQL database, however when the call is made to send a query to the log table, the user is read from ViewState. What I believe is happening is that the APPPool user is somehow overriding the user previously set in ViewState. Is that even possible?

Comment: Are you sure the user is being read from ViewState? Unless you are explicitly impersonating the user coming from the SQL database, IIS will send the application pool credentials through to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Normally a website process (w3wp.exe) impersonates the identity of the application pool identity (IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool)

Unless you are using Integrated Authentication, in which the website process impersonates the identity of the authenticated user account accessing it (YOURDOMAIN\YourUsername).

What your site does beyond that is separate from IIS authentication and totally up to your application - that is, if you then go and set your users from your database, etc.